# Copying from WHS 2011 backup very slow

Tags: backup, performance, file-transfer, restore, windows-home-server

I'm setting up a new computer to replace one of my old ones, and part of doing so is extracting my Home folder from a backup I made just before wiping the old one. However, copying from the mounted drive is proceeding at the glacial pace of roughly 80-90 Kb/s (Normal file transfer is working fine at 95 Mb/s), despite the fact that I have a Gigabit Ethernet connection hooked up between the server and target computer. Is there a way to speed up this transfer? At this rate, it'll be another 34 hours or so before it finishes copying.

If it helps, attempting a complete restore is much faster...

Comment: Without more informatin we cannot help.  There is no way to "force" a transfer to happen faster.

Comment: @Ramhound: What information do you need?